# Symfony bundle scaffolding with subfolders

Tags: symfony, frontend, scaffolding

According to this well-known article:
https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2011/05/19/symfony2-bundle-structure-a-use-case.html

Is there a fast way to scaffold a bundle with Frontend and Backend subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of something like that. And I don't see any advantage of it.

This also means I don't think you should have both backend and frontend in the same bundle. Id avise you to make two seperate bundles.

- Project\Something\BackendBundle
- Project\Something\FrontendBundle

You can do that using `app/console generate:bundle`

This will result in a Project/Something folder structure with both bundles in the same **Something** folder.

Comment: So, in your example, "Something" is a functionality containing front and back bundles. In the article, the bundle represents the functionality having front and backend controllers and views. Which way to choose? To be honest, I am new in Symfony and I am looking for best practices in separating front and backend. The way explained in the article works well, but manually creating the structure is terrible...

Comment: Yes, so reading the blog article I would create a Liip\Event\BackendBundle and a Liip\Event\FrontendBundle.
Then the routing could be like /event/* for the frontend and /event/admin/* for the backend.